# why does this python script wait till the timer thread is executed?

Tags: python, execution

```
from threading import Timer

def startTimer():

  t = Timer(10.0, foo, ['hello world', 'tell me more'] )
  t.start()
  print 'Timer function invoked'
  print 'function exit'

def foo(msg, msg2):
  print 'foo was executed'
  print msg
  print msg2

if __name__ == '__main__':  
  startTimer()
  print 'end of program'
```

I've saved the above code in a file (timer.py), and then typed python timer.py in the shell. But it waited until foo() was executed. Why is this so? What do you call this behaviour/style of execution?

Comment: Did you expect it to exit before the thread would run at all?

Comment: yeah. I mean wouldn't this happen if you ran a similar code in .net/java...

Comment: "What do you call this behaviour/style of execution?" The default behavior of threads created by the `Timer` class.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Timer is just a thread and Python waits for all non-`daemonic` threads before stopping the interpreter.

> A thread can be flagged as a “daemon
>   thread”. The significance of this flag
>   is that the entire Python program
>   exits when only daemon threads are
>   left. The initial value is inherited
>   from the creating thread. The flag can
>   be set through the daemon property.

[from the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#thread-objects)

Set `the_timer.daemon=True` and Python will exit right away instead of waiting for the timer.